# font-style as a base styling also for child elements using % or em

Tags: css, font-size

How can I declare in CSS `font-style` as a base styling also for child elements using star item, while not using fixed "px" values, only "em" or "%"?

The only thing I thought of is:

```
* {
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table, tbody, form, tr, td  {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

Is there a better approach?

Note: declaring the first `font-size` in order to rely proportionally on the browser's default font sizing. It works fine for all fonts excepts those are under child elements (such as `td`).

`td` font size is 150%, then `tr` font size that is 150%, then its parent `tbody` that is 150% from its parent table that — if directly bound to the body — gets the 150% as declared from the beginning (150% from browser defalut).

In order to fix that the last child gets the same `font-size`, I used `font-size: inherit;`

Comment: Upside.. That will work... Downside... good luck over-riding that if you ever need to..

Comment: it's `inherit`.

Answer (score 1):

You typed inherit wrong:

```
table, tbody, form, tr ,td,  {
  font-size: inhereat;
}
```

Do this:

```
table, tbody, form, tr ,td,  {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

But also you don't need the above code because you had the `font-size` for `*` be something which means everything (`*`) will have the `font-size`. So you don't need to say to `inherit` the `font-size` of itself.

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello world!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just setting the font-size on the `body` element? All children will inherit unless having their own styling.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>
      2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```